# How to check (whether after clicking on drop-down), drop-down is populated using Selenium Webdriver with Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I want to check whether clicking on drop-down populates drop-down. Following is my web page code -

```
<div class="selectWrapper">
 <div class="mask"></div>
   <select selected="15" name="timezone_id">
     <option -1100="" value="67">Samoa Standard Time (GMT-11)</option>
     .
     .
     .
     .
```

By following code, drop-down is clicked & we get all options-

```
driver.find_element(:name, "timezone_id").click (actually we need not to click to get     all options)
options = time_zone.find_elements(:tag_name => "option")

timezone_options = options.map do |option|
  option.text
end
```

But how can we make sure that the drop-down is populated or not?

Comment: Do you want to check if the value is selected or not?

Comment: No, I don't want to check if value is selected or not?

Comment: Okay, then please specify clearly what you mean by click on `dropdown`?

Comment: Actually, I want to check that after clicking, drop-down should be displayed. Sometimes, it happens that we click, but drop-down isn't shown.

Comment: If your page loaded, then fields of that page will be there obviously present,but sometimes not. But the values are not loaded I have never found. BTW you want to check if the all values of that dropdown field is present or not? something like that. Your question is not much clear thus couldn't give you the solution. If possible please edit your post with your expectation and what you got things.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, I think the only thing you can do to check is to check the attribute which causes certain elements to be invisible in the dropdown by using getAttribute on the option element. so for eg if you have display:none marked for an element, then check for that attribute for each element.